# Sending parameters to a stored procedure - PLS-00049

Tags: oracle, bind, procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TABULA.GetTorimByDoctor (
   DOCTORID IN CHAR,
   CUSTOMERID IN CHAR,
   DEFTYPE IN CHAR,
   p_out_rec        OUT sys_refcursor
) AS
BEGIN
   SELECT
    to_date(TO_DATE('01-01-1988 00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') + numtodsinterval(w.curdate, 'minute'),'dd-mm-yyyy') AS qdate,
    to_char(trunc(sysdate) + h.stime / 24 / 60, 'hh24:mi') AS stime,
    to_char(trunc(sysdate) +(h.stime +(
        CASE
            WHEN((macdent$mac_cyaskill.durdef <> 0)) THEN
                (macdent$mac_cyaskill.durdef)
...
```

I get an error of

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
80/27     PLS-00049: 'DOCTORID'  bad bind variable
126/27    PLS-00049: 'CUSTOMERID' bad bind variable
127/23    PLS-00049: 'DEFTYPE'  bad bind variable
Errors: check compiler log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who knows, you didn't post the whole code, but I *suspect* that you preceded parameters' names with a colon within the procedure (lines 80, 126, 127).

Here's an illustration of what you (probably) did:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gettorimbydoctor (doctorid IN CHAR)
  2  AS
  3     l_cnt  NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT COUNT (*)
  6       INTO l_cnt
  7       FROM DUAL
  8      WHERE 'a' = :doctorid;         --> colon here
  9  END;
 10  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE GETTORIMBYDOCTOR:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
8/17     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'DOCTORID'
SQL>
```

If that's so, remove colon:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gettorimbydoctor (doctorid IN CHAR)
  2  AS
  3     l_cnt  NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT COUNT (*)
  6       INTO l_cnt
  7       FROM DUAL
  8      WHERE 'a' = doctorid;
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```